# Several TCP connections with java URLConnection

Tags: java, urlconnection

I have made a simple HTTP client, which downloads a set of URLs parsed from a webpage.

My problem is that the download is slow, compared to a real browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome). Especially if the page contains many objects.

I noticed (with wireshark) that many times the real browsers will setup 5-10 TCP connections within the same millisecond instantly after starting the load of a page. Those conections will then live concurrently for a period of time.

My client will also setup concurrent TCP-connections (and it will reuse TCP connections), but not at all this aggressively. I'm guessing that this is one of the reasons my client is slower.

I have tried creating several URLConnections before reading from the input stream, but this does not work for me. I am inexperienced though, so I probably do it wrong.

Does anyone know of way to do this (mimic what the browsers are doing in terms of TCP connection setup) with URLConnection?

Comment: are you creating a separate thread for each URLConnection on which to download the data?

Comment: Thanks for the response! No, I have just created separate URLConnection objects. I guess I should run them in separate threads. Hmmm, can I do that and still have only one input stream listener?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using HttpClient:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

It has support for internal connection management, pooling etc.
Browsers tend to have this sort of stuff.

Things may have changed since I last used it, but UrlConnection didn't work well for production apps.  Ex. it didn't have a clean way to shut it down.

Comment: I think you are right. I started out with URLConnection (and HTTPUrlConnection) and it's hard to break free :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using a high performance networking library, like [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/). This will automatically create thread pool for you and save you a lot of time.